# How to call a Stored Procedure from a Scheduled Event in MySql using PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am using PhpMyAdmin console for my MySQL DB.
I have a Routine in DB and I want to call the routine on the last date of every month. 
I set up an event and for testing purpose I have set it for 1 min interval:

```
CREATE EVENT `monthly_report` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2014-02-05 07:50:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO CALL Test_Proc()
```

But it is never been called.
Can anyone help me?

Regards,
Surodip

Comment: May be I found the problem. My DB name is test.db and having dot(.) in my db name the procedure may not be found in event.
If this can be a possibility can anyone help me to deal with the dot(.) in db name?

-Surodip

Comment: Is the Event Scheduler active? From the Events tab, there's an area that says "Event scheduler status" -- is that toggle set to "On"?